# store order id and timestamp on successful checkout in custom table

Tags: magento-1.8, controllers

As the question is self explanatory but for more details I need to store the `order id` and `timestamp` of the order creation in a separate table.

What my boss asked me to do is to user overriding ([for reference shown here](http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-part10-series-overriding)). But I'm unable to figure it out whether I need to override a block or controller, and which one?
One of my peer suggested me to override the `Checkout/OnepageController`'s `successAction()`. But neither the *overriding* of controller worked nor I'm able to get the *timestamp* there.

I'd gone through [this blog of magento commerce](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/how_to_overload_a_controller) but the `OnepageController` not getting overridden.

P.S: Before down vote please let me know what is wrong with that?

Comment: Means you need if any user place a order then you have to save order id and time stamp in your custom table am I right?

Comment: If yes Then I will provide you solutions.

Comment: @KeyulShah: yes...

Comment: please see the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are the steps to create the above feature.

1) Hope you create the module and create your custom table via script.

2) You have to create the observer for `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action`

```
<global>
 <events>
  <checkout_onepage_controller_success_action> <!-- identifier of the event we want to catch -->
    <observers>
      <sales_order_place_after_handler> <!-- any unique identifier of the event handler -->
        <type>singleton</type> <!-- class method call type; valid are model, object and singleton -->
        <class>[modulename]/observer</class> <!-- observers class alias -->
        <method>[Your Method Name]</method>  <!-- observer's method to be called -->
        <args></args> <!-- additional arguments passed to observer -->
      </sales_order_place_after_handler>
    </observers>
  </checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
 </events>
</global>
```

3) create the `Observer.php` file in `namespace/modulename/Model/Observer.php`

and code is like below.

```
<?php
  class [Namespace]_[ModuleName]_Model_Observer
  {
     private function [Your Method Name](Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
     {
           $order = $observer -> getEvent() -> getOrder();
           // write your saving code  
     }
   }
?>
```

If you Trace It working or not then try to log massage using `Mage::Log('test message')`. and this file will store in `var\Log` folder.

**Note:** I Just Copy and paste the code you have to replace with your module names.

Comment: as I'm getting it correctly then in step 2, the **xml** code should be placed in `config.xml` but under which tag it will go?

Comment: under `<global>`

Comment: as if i'm getting it correctly then I can know about the `<checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>` from `OnepageController`'s `successAction()` code `Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_onepage_controller_success_action', array('order_ids' => array($lastOrderId)));`. But `<sales_order_place_after_handler>` where do it came from?

Comment: its a unique name of event you can put any thing

Comment: okay... I need to test it and then I'll accept your answer. Thanks for the help. +1

Comment: I think your are confused please open this link http://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/

and write your company name, module name and select Need `Add Magento Event` and `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action` name, method and select type . after that `create the module`. you got whole code in zip and study the code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12611/discussion-between-mohammad-faisal-and-keyul-shah)